# Изменение одной строки во многих файлах

Tags: файлы, редактор, редактор-текста

Всем привет.Есть множество файлов (пусть 50), в них есть одинаковая ссылка.Ее необходимо изменить на другую во всех файлах.Кто может подсказать как это сделать быстро?Идеально было бы сделать это в редакторе Brackets или Sublime.Файлы .html

Comment: кто-то может. // вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Comment: `PS> ls *.txt -rec | %{$f=$_; (gc $f.PSPath) | %{$_ -replace "oldlink", "newlink"} | sc $f.PSPath}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте Notepad++.

**1-й Вариант - открывая все нужные файлы**

1) Откройте все файлы в нём;

2) нажмите Поиск-Замена;

3) Заполните поля "Найти", "Заменить на".

4) Нажмите "Заменить во всех открытых документах"

**2-й вариант - без открытия всех файлов**

1) Откройте один любой файл из нужной папки;

2) нажмите Поиск-Замена, вкладка Найти в файлах;

3) Заполните поля "Найти", "Заменить на", укажите папку для замены (если нужно, отметьте "заменить в подпапках").

4) Нажмите "Заменить в файлах"

Для поиска вы также можете использовать регулярные выражения (если нужно)

Comment: Не подойдет..Это слишком муторно..При таком решении мне необходимо открывать 50 или 100 к примеру файлов(в зависимости от количества).Может есть плагин какой-то для редакторов или что-то в этом духе, чтобы осуществить это через работу с директорией или папкой..

Comment: Операционная система windows 7 если это необходимо знать

Comment: открыли папку - выделили все файлы - правая кнопка - открыть с помощью notepad++ - дальше то, что уже писал.... или просто в notepad++ файл-открыть и выбрать все файлы (через shift первый и последний файл)

Comment: Хорошо, думаю подойдет.Всяко не часто подобное используешь. Просто думал есть более элегантный способ..Но спасибо. +1 к ауре добра.